# Фиксация кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Доброе время суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой с кнопкой. После нажатия на кнопку - открываеться браузер со ссылкой на ту станицу. При возвращении опять в приложение, то кнопка грубо говоря исчезает(Ну, она не исчезает, а переноситься в самый угол окна, на которую нажать проблематично)
Как мне зафиксировать место расположение кнопки?
Вот сам код:

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/idImageView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/yads1_1"
     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/idButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="check"
     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="221dp"
     android:onClick="buttonClick"
     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

То есть принажатии на кнопку - сама кнопка перемещаеться в самый край экрана

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так вы ей не задали никаких привязок. Поучитесь работать с `ConstraintLayout` (например здесь: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого рода привязки `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` - работают только в предпросмоторщике. Удалите их и никогда не используйте. Скорее всего они у вас появились после ручного передвижения вьюхи в предпросмоторщике.

Вместо ручного перемещения лучше прямо в XML прописывайте нужные привязки в атрибутах тэга.